# Scrapy xpath selector not parsing

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape https://www.grailed.com/ using scrapy. I have been able to get the elements I want in each listing (price, item title, size). I currently trying to get the `ahrefs` for each listing at the home page.

When I try `response.xpath('.//div[starts-with(@id, "product")]').extract`
returns

```
<bound method SelectorList.extract of [<Selector xpath='.//div[starts-with(@id, "product")]' 
data=u'<div id="products">\n<div id="loading">\n<'>]>
```

Based on the inspect element it should be returning `div class="feed-wrapper">`?

I'm just trying to get those links so scrapy knows to go into each listing. Thank you for any help.

Comment: I don't have scrapy, but loading into `lxml` the xpath works as expected. The error says that _extract_ is a method and perhaps you need cowboy legs to call it (use `.extract()`)_.What was the actual error? There should be more info after "bound method...".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do scrapping always check source of page (not in the inspector but view-source) - that would be real data you operate with.

That div is added dynamically after page loads. JS does that job.
When you send request to server and receive pure HTML - JS will not be executed and so you see real Server response which you support to work with.

> div class="feed-wrapper">

Here is real Server response to you. You must deal with it.

[image]

Comment: This being the case, any advice to grab these links? The other option is the listing URLs themselves. They follow `https://www.grailed.com/listings/"[n +1] number here" `. How would I tell Scrapy to say go to https://www.grailed.com/listings/220327 and get info and  then   https://www.grailed.com/listings/220328 until it hits a 404 (there might be no 220329 for instance)? This is my first Python project, thank you for the advice!

Comment: How to scrapy the dynamic html. is it possible? Thanks in advanced